# Unexpexted Token: 'A6tEZ'

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, id

I am getting this error, My query looks fine when I check it with Debug Logs -

```
List<Account> lstAccount = new List<Account>();

     String query = 'select ' + commaSepratedFields + ' from Account where id=' +apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');

lstAccount = Database.executeQuery(query);
```

VF PAGE :

```
<apex:repeat id="repeatid" value="{!lstAccount}" var="acc">
<apex:outputText value="{!acc.name}>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Try the following: `String query = 'select ' + commaSepratedFields + ' from Account where id=\'' +apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id') + '\'';`

Comment: Yah !!! It worked. Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because my comment actually answered the question I decided to post it as an answer.

Your problem is in this line:

```
String query = 'select ' + commaSepratedFields + ' from Account where id=' +apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
```

which makes a query like:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Account Where Id = abc123
```

but `Id` is a `String`(or at least it is used as one in the code), so you need to add single quote marks around it. To do so you have to use `\'`(read more about [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) if you are not familiar with it). So this line of code should become:

```
String query = 'select ' + commaSepratedFields + ' from Account where id=\'' +apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id') + '\'';
```

Comment: Ok, Got it, Now One more thing except above question, I have queried all Dynamic fields in the Account, How can I show all of them on the VF page.